# how can I connect the points of the lines in order?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

[image]

how can I connect the dots with a line in order? in geometric nodes

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points to curves has a "curve group ID" as input:

[image]

If you take the points coordinates and the wanted axis, multiplied by some big values (1000 here, but which depens on the density of the point cloud) so that each consecutive point corresponds to a distinct integer value (in both axis),

Then multiply that by 2 distinct primary numbers. I think the ID should be unique.

---

If you want to keep only the side parts (say, on X axis),

[image]

You can compare the x coordinate to the bounding box with some epsilon value, and delete the points in this interval.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I remove the lines in the center, only the side ones on both sides are needed?

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot

Comment: how can I replace the "Boundin Box" with the selected shape? if the shape is not even, then the lines are not deleted. I have attached a new blender file.